# passing json data from client to service

Tags: json, wcf, service, client

I'm trying to add RESTful architecture to existing SOAP service, so that I have both Rest and SOAP compliant service. I'm accessorising existing methods in service interface with WebGets and WebInvokes. As it is seen from the method signature Object is passed as a parameter and Object is returned from the method. That's why following http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/327420/WCF-REST-Service-with-JSON I'm using Json as message format. In chrome addon Advanced Rest Client there is a nice feature of sending json data while POSTing query. But what I can't get my head around is how client in my system is supposed to send Json data when calling this service?

here is call from client:

```
client.GenerateInvitation(sessionId, email, loggedInstitution);
```

service interface:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke( Method = "POST",ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "Rest/GenerateInvitation?ses={sessionId}&em={email}"]
        PartialInvitation GenerateInvitation(string sessionId, string email, Institution  institution);
```

Here is data contract:

```
  public partial class Institution
      {

    [DataMember]
        public System.Guid Guid { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Phonenumber { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is a implemented method GenerateInvitation:

```
public PartialInvitation GenerateInvitation(string sessionId, string email, Institution institution)
        {
            Session session = GetSession(sessionId);
            if (session != null)
            {
                if (((  session.User.Institutions.Where(i => i.Guid ==             institution.Guid).FirstOrDefault() != null &&
                                session.User.AccessLevel == ACCESS_LEVEL_MED
                            ) ||  session.User.AccessLevel == ACCESS_LEVEL_HIGH
                        ) && EmailTools.IsValidEmail(email) )
                {
                    List<User> usersWithMatchingEmail = db.Users.Where(u => u.Email == email).ToList();

                    foreach (User usr in usersWithMatchingEmail)
                    {
                        if (session.User.AccessLevel == ACCESS_LEVEL_MED)
                        {
                            if (usr.AccessLevel != ACCESS_LEVEL_LOW) throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot invite non trainees");
                        }
                        if (session.User.AccessLevel == ACCESS_LEVEL_HIGH)
                        {
                            if (usr.AccessLevel == ACCESS_LEVEL_HIGH) throw new InvalidOperationException("Admin's cannot invite each other, they have full power without invitations");
                        }
                    }
                    List<Invitation> invitations = db.Invitations.Where(i => i.Email == email).ToList();
                    Invitation invitation = invitations.Where(i => i.Institution.Guid == institution.Guid).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (invitation == null)
                    {
                        invitation = new Invitation
                        {
                            Guid = Guid.NewGuid(),
                            Email = email,
                            Institution = db.Institutions.Where(i => i.Guid == institution.Guid).FirstOrDefault(),
                            InvitationCode = Convert.ToBase64String(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray()).Substring(0, 8).ToUpper(),
                            InvitedOn = DateTime.Now,
                            ExpiresOn = DateTime.Now.AddDays(INVITATION_EXPIRY_DAYS),
                            InvitedBy = session.User
                        };

                        while ((db.Invitations.Where(i => i.InvitationCode == invitation.InvitationCode).FirstOrDefault()) != null)
                        {
                            invitation.InvitationCode = Convert.ToBase64String(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray()).Substring(0, 8).ToUpper();
                        }

                        if (invitation.Institution != null)
                        {
                            db.Invitations.Add(invitation);
                            db.SaveChanges();
                            SendInvitation(invitation);
                            return PartialInvitation.FromInvitation(invitation);
                        }
                    }
                    SendInvitation(invitation);
                    return PartialInvitation.FromInvitation(invitation);
                }
            }
            return null; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Client code cannot be generated when using WCF REST, so your client is probably still connected to your SOAP endpoint. To generate a Rest client check out the following blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2008/04/21/how-to-consume-rest-services-with-wcf.aspx

Comment: thank you. but it is using XmlSerializerFormat not JSON. any advices on that?

Comment: In your question you asked how to post JSON requests to your service. Do you want to post JSON or XML to your service?